# Conda environment name shows entire directory in prompt

Tags: anaconda, command-prompt, conda, iterm2, iterm

When I run:

> source activate /anaconda2/envs/myEnv

it shows the entire directory of this conda environment in my prompt (on iterm2) as so:

```
(/Users/billy/anaconda2/envs/myEnv)billy@mbp:~/projects
```

Is this a way to shorten this, so that it just shows the name of the conda environment and not the entire directory? For example as:

```
(myEnv)billy@mbp:~/projects
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try the following:

Make sure that `/anaconda2/envs` is listed in the section `envs_dirs` in the output for the command:

```
$ conda config --show
```

If it is not present, you can add it like this:

```
$ conda config --add envs_dirs /anaconda2/envs
```

Then, activate the environment like this:

```
$ source activate myEnv
```

Example:

```
(root) ~/condaexpts ❯❯❯ conda create -yp /tmp/miniconda2/myEnv
Fetching package metadata .......
.Solving package specifications: .
Package plan for installation in environment /tmp/miniconda2/myEnv:

The following empty environments will be CREATED:

/tmp/miniconda2/myEnv

#
# To activate this environment, use:
# > source activate /tmp/miniconda2/myEnv
#
# To deactivate this environment, use:
# > source deactivate /tmp/miniconda2/myEnv
#

(root) ~/condaexpts ❯❯❯ conda config --add envs_dirs /tmp/miniconda2
(root) ~/condaexpts ❯❯❯ source activate myEnv
(myEnv) ~/condaexpts ❯❯❯
```

Comment: The command "conda config --show" shows an error: "conda config: error: one of the arguments --get --add --set --remove --remove-key is required"

Comment: @Learnaholic What is the version of conda that you are using?

Comment: Try updating conda to 4.3.5 and see if the problem persists?

Comment: Cool thanks, that did it, although upgrading conda also upgraded my python. :-/

Comment: Also, "conda activate myEnv" doesnt work, it says you have to do "source activate myEnv".

Comment: This doesn't appear to work anymore in `4.5.11`. Even if you add the path to `envs_dirs`, it still prints the whole path.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the `env_prompt` option in the config file, see [Specifying a location for an environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#specifying-a-location-for-an-environment).

One option is `conda config --set env_prompt '({name})'` or you can edit the `.condarc` in your home directory. Just add `env_prompt: '({name})'`.