# Modiyfing conda configuration file does not reflect changes in environment

Tags: anaconda, conda, virtual-environment

I am trying to change the default installation location for Conda environments because the system I am using (a supercomputing cluster) has a ~20GB user home quota. Under normal circumstances, this could easily be done by editing `~/.condarc` and adding a portion `envs_dirs`, which is explained quite well in [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41656131/conda-environment-name-shows-entire-directory-in-prompt).

However, it seems that the compute environment I am in (i.e., with the supercomputer), does not let me modify the *priority* of various locations for environments. In an ideal world, I would be able to place `/work/helikarlab/joshl/.conda/envs` at the top of the list, which is a high-storage partition, so I can install additional environments if needed.

My `~/.condarc` is configured as follows:

```yaml
env_prompt: ({name})
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
auto_activate_base: false
envs_dirs:
  - /work/helikarlab/joshl/.conda/envs/
```

Yet, I observe the following entries with `conda config --show envs_dirs`

```yaml
envs_dirs:
  - /home/helikarlab/joshl/.conda/envs
  - /util/opt/anaconda/deployed-conda-envs/packages/python/envs
  - /util/opt/anaconda/deployed-conda-envs/packages/perl/envs
  - /util/opt/anaconda/deployed-conda-envs/packages/git/envs
  - /util/opt/anaconda/deployed-conda-envs/packages/nano/envs
  - /work/helikarlab/joshl/.conda/envs
  - /home/helikarlab/joshl/.conda/envs/base_env/envs
```

Does anyone know why my attempt set `envs_dirs` is not working? How can I set the `/work/helikarlab/joshl/.conda/envs` to the highest priority?

---

### Additional Info

Here is the result from `conda config --show-sources`

```yaml
==> /util/opt/anaconda/4.9.2/.condarc <==
allow_softlinks: False
auto_update_conda: False
auto_activate_base: False
notify_outdated_conda: False
repodata_threads: 4
verify_threads: 4
execute_threads: 2
aggressive_update_packages: []
pkgs_dirs:
  - ${WORK}/.conda/pkgs
  - ${HOME}/.conda/pkgs
channel_priority: disabled
channels:
  - hcc
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/t/<TOKEN>/hcc
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
  - file:///util/opt/conda_repo

==> /home/helikarlab/joshl/.condarc <==
auto_activate_base: False
env_prompt: ({name})
envs_dirs:
  - /work/helikarlab/joshl/.conda/envs/
channel_priority: disabled
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults

==> envvars <==
envs_path:
  - /home/helikarlab/joshl/.conda/envs
  - /util/opt/anaconda/deployed-conda-envs/packages/python/envs
  - /util/opt/anaconda/deployed-conda-envs/packages/perl/envs
  - /util/opt/anaconda/deployed-conda-envs/packages/git/envs
  - /util/opt/anaconda/deployed-conda-envs/packages/nano/envs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Background: Conda's configuration priorities

As documented in ["*The Conda Configuration Engine for Power Users*" post](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/conda-configuration-engine-power-users), Conda sources configuration values from four sources, listed from lowest to highest priority:

1. Default values in the Python code
2. `.condarc` configuration files (system < user < environment < working directory)
3. Environment variables (`CONDA_*` variables)
4. Command-line specifications

### Problem: Environment variable prioritized

We can observe how this plays out in OP's case, with the `--show-sources` result. Specifically, there are three places where `envs_dirs` is defined:

1. System level configuration file at `/util/opt/anaconda/4.9.2/.condarc`
2. User-level configuration file at `/home/helikarlab/joshl/.condarc`
3. Environment variable `CONDA_ENVS_PATH`<sup>**1**</sup>

And since the environment variable takes priority and defines the preferred directory to be `/home/helikarlab/joshl/.conda/envs`, that will take precedence no matter what is set with `conda config` and `.condarc` files.

### Workarounds

All the following workarounds involve manipulating the environment variable. It is unclear when the variable is set (probably via a system-level shell configuration file). It should be reliable to manipulate the variable by appending any of the following workarounds to user-level shell configuration file (e.g., `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.zshrc`).

#### Option 1: Unset variable

One could completely remove the variable with

```bash
unset CONDA_ENVS_PATH
```

This would then allow the user-level `.condarc` to take priority.

However, this variable also appears to provide locations for several system-level shared environments. It is unclear how integral these shared environments are for normal functionality. So, removing the variable altogether could have additional consequences.

#### Option 2: Replace value

Conveniently, the location default and desired locations differ only by replacing `/home` with `/work`. This could be changed directly in the variable with:

```bash
export CONDA_ENVS_PATH=${CONDA_ENVS_PATH/\/home/\/work}
```

#### Option 3: Prepend desired default

The most general override would be to prepend the desired default path to the environment variable:

```bash
export CONDA_ENVS_PATH="/work/helikarlab/joshl/.conda/envs/:${CONDA_ENVS_PATH}"
```

This is probably the most robust, since it assumes nothing about the inherited value.

## Additional Note

Users with small disk quotas in default locations should also consider moving the package cache (`pkgs_dirs`) to coordinate with the environments directory. Details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67612296/570918).

---

<sub>**[1]:** `CONDA_ENVS_DIRS` and `CONDA_ENVS_PATH` are interchangeable, however only one can be defined at time. The former is the contemporary usage, so I believe the latter is likely supported for backward compatibility.</sub>

Comment: This is a beautiful answer, thank you! I opted with option 3 placed at the end of my `~/.bashrc` file. Note: I had to change `CONDA_ENV_PATH` to `CONDA_ENVS_PATH` (note the extra 's'), otherwise it did not work

Comment: @JoshLoecker oops, so sorry for the typo- fixed now